# Laravel project is calling the wrong paths

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel and I am testing out an application that i have made. locally it works fine but when  I push it to a server, then the routing seems to go really bad. Usually a path to a view would be like `156.0.125.1/app/index`, but it keeps looking for 156.0.125.1/index which gives the error of URL not found on server

I suspect its the .htaccess file but I'm not too sure what to change there as I'm not familiar with it.

also the css and the js seem to not be read by the site on the server

heres the htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Disable Directory listing
Options -Indexes

# block files which needs to be hidden, specify .example extension of the file
<Files ~ "\.(env|json|config.js|md|gitignore|gitattributes|lock)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Welcome, are you able to supply the contents of the .htaccess?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add that, its there now

Answer (score 0):

Move this file app/public/index.php to your server document root

and make the following changes
Change
'''
require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php
'''
to
'''
require **DIR**.'/app/vendor/autoload.php
'''
Change
'''
require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php
'''
to
'''
require_once **DIR**.'/app/bootstrap/app.php
'''
In app/server.php make the following changes

Change
'''
require_once **DIR**.'/public/index.php
'''
to
'''
require_once **DIR**.'/../index.php
'''

Comment: Okay, could you walk me through what this would do?

Comment: I already have an index.php in the root but its not the same one as the on in the public folder

Comment: @Juststartedcoding the public/index.php file is the entry point of your laravel application and it should be at your server document root. The changes are just to modify the path from the script calling the public/index.php file, and the path of the scripts being called from the file, since it has been moved. Enable debug mode and check the cause of the 500 error